# Safely aborting thrid-party code using TPL

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net, task-parallel-library

I'm using some third-party libraries in my project. Once in a while the code in these libraries freaks out and produces infinite loops and other nasty things. My goal is to write a wrapper that allows me to abort execution of this third-party code after some timeout. Here's my current implementation:

```
public static class SafeExecutor
{
    public static async Task DoAsync(Action action, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("action");
        if (timeout <= TimeSpan.Zero) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("timeout");

        var completed = await tryCompleteAsync(action, timeout).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (!completed)
        {
            throw new TimeoutException();
        }
    }

    public static void Do(Action action, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        DoAsync(action, timeout).Wait();
    }

    public static async Task<T> ReturnAsync<T>(Func<T> function, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        if (function == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("function");
        if (timeout <= TimeSpan.Zero) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("timeout");

        var value = default(T);
        var completed = await tryCompleteAsync(() => value = function(), timeout).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (!completed)
        {
            throw new TimeoutException();
        }

        return value;
    }

    public static T Return<T>(Func<T> function, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        return ReturnAsync(function, timeout).Result;
    }

    private static async Task<bool> tryCompleteAsync(Action action, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        using (var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout))
        {
            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(
                () =>
                {
                    var abortCookie = Guid.NewGuid();
                    try
                    {
                        var currentThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
                        using (tokenSource.Token.Register(() => currentThread.Abort(abortCookie)))
                        {
                            action();
                        }

                        return true;
                    }
                    catch (ThreadAbortException ex)
                    {
                        if (ex.ExceptionState != null && ex.ExceptionState.Equals(abortCookie))
                        {
                            Thread.ResetAbort();
                            return false;
                        }

                        throw;
                    }

                }, tokenSource.Token);

            return await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should add a cancellationtoken parameter, if you want to be able to cancel it on demand